# How to get rid of banners from Stack Exchange when not logged in?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

If I view a Stack Exchange page without being logged in there are three banners which I have to remove first before browsing. The page looks for example like this:

[image]

That's totally unusable for me. As I remember those banners are a relatively new "feature".

Is there any trick to get rid of the banners when not logged in for example by tweaking some cookie settings in my browser or by blocking specific IP's in my hosts file (I am working with ubuntu 18.04)?

Comment: This is already being addressed in [Can we show new/anonymous users more Q&A?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314134/289905).

Comment: I don't think so, because that question is about the design of the stackexchange page and my question is about if there are any "tricks" such that I can get rid of the banners as user (in particular not by waiting if the developers change the site design).

Comment: Other than a userscript, I don’t know what “tricks” there could be.

Comment: You could use an adblocker to zap all elements you don't want to see.

Comment: I don’t think this is a duplicate. The answer to the proposed duplicate isn’t the same as the answer to this question. The answer to this question could be wait until the problem identified in that other question is fixed, but that’s a related question, not a duplicate.

Comment: add `*##.js-dismissable-hero.ps-relative.sm\:pb24.sm\:pt24.fc-black-200.bg-black-750.py24` to uBlockOrigin 'My Filters'

Comment: Also, I would go on a long masked but profanity laden tyrade on how utterly disgusted I am with these banners trying to bully me into log in, along with having to log in to multiple SE subsites, but I wont risk this solution that hopefully gets so many views that it starts a revolt among SE users to remove this nonsense that detracts from the site's normal and pragmatic use by normal and pragmatic people.