# Link to parent site on the sidebar for per-site-metas

Tags: feature-request, design, per-site-meta, sidebar

In my opinion, the sidebar in the new theme is helpful but underused.

[image: sidebar]

The sidebar could be helpful, but it has too few useful links, which makes it a waste of space. One possible use of all of this space is in going from a meta site to the parent site. Currently, the easiest way to get from a meta site to the parent site is by using the menu on the top right.

For me, that means moving the mouse over to the button, pressing it, waiting for the menu to pop up, and having to scan over the communities to get to the current community. As soon as my eyes have moved there, the sites list loads, making me involuntarily look down to see what the motion is. Then I have to remember exactly what I was doing, look back at the communities list, move the mouse over to the parent site and click it.

I know this isn't a major inconvenience, but I think that the side menu could speed up this process.

Messing around with the Inspect tool, I created these two screenshots of what the sidebar might look like with the new link. Keep in mind that I am neither a professional developer nor a UX expert, so the link could be moved below the home link and/or change to look like the links below.

[image: link above home, no space]

[image: link below home, spacing]

In my opinion, this would make the sidebar more useful and speed up switching between the parent and meta sites. Does this make the site easier to use, and if so, is it possible to add to the new theme?

Comment: Lots of similar requests have been made recently, and in the past, I'm only listing them to show the SE team that users keep suggesting the same ideas but they all eventually end up on the heap.

Comment: Related: **1** [Make the chat link one click away in the new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210095/make-the-chat-link-one-click-away-in-the-new-top-bar) **2** [Put the right column into the new theme's left column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315597/put-the-right-column-into-the-new-themes-left-column) **3** [Why do we have two sidebar columns instead of combining them into one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316019/why-do-we-have-two-sidebar-columns-instead-of-combining-them-into-one)

Comment: **4** [Three “hamburgers” but no direct link to meta. Is this an example of “Good Design”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315895/three-hamburgers-but-no-direct-link-to-meta-is-this-an-example-of-good-desig)

Comment: Mari-Lou That would definitely be a helpful change, why do these proposals get ignored/declined? Do the developers not want any of these changes or do they just not have the time to work on it?

Comment: They are probably busy rolling out the new responsive theme to all the sites in the network. Hopefully they will be able to implement these features once the rollout is complete.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oops, for got the @ see above comment

Comment: @KodosJohnson Weren't similar changes requested before they started work on the new theme?

Comment: Perhaps. But there was this proposal which includes your requested feature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311456/299995. And it is tagged as status-review so I am hoping they will adopt it. Also, I think I recall SE staff saying that they are planning to add more to the left sidebar later.

Comment: No probs. Johnson gave you much better answers than I could

Comment: @KodosJohnson I saw that, it looks really useful. That would be an awesome feature.